# How does Regeneration interact with drugs?

Tags: healing, shadowrun-sr4, shapeshifting, medicine-and-drugs

Shadowrun Shapeshifters are among the most durable enemies one could face, unless one is armed with silver weaponry or magic, because they have the Regeneration trait. This heals them up by a substantial amount each round.

> A critter with Regeneration rapidly heals any damage. At the end
> of a Combat Turn, make a Magic + Body Test. Each hit regenerates 1
> point of Physical or Stun damage. If a critter has already taken enough
> damage to enter into Physical damage overflow, the critter is not considered
> dead until it has had a chance to make a Regeneration Test. After
> a critter has made a Regeneration Test, if the damage overflow is still
> greater than the critter’s Body attribute, then the critter is dead.
> Certain types of damage cannot be regenerated from this power.
> Damage to the brain or spinal cord (for example, from a called shot to the head) cannot be healed this way. Likewise, magical damage
> from weapon foci, combat spells, critter/adept powers, or other
> magic may not be healed through Regeneration. If the critter has
> an Allergy, the critter cannot regenerate damage until the allergen’s
> presence is removed.

Most drugs and toxins inflict some sort of damage in some way.

However, I can not fathom how Regeneration interacts with drugs:

- Does someone benefiting from this power get no effect at all from
  drugs (neither positive, nor negative)?
- Do they gain only the upsides?
- Or do they gain the full effects, but heal much faster from any
  damage that the substance inflicts?